# call a function with different parameters in setInterval

Tags: php, function, parameters, setinterval

I am using setInterval function to call a function after a particular time intervals.
**Code is given below:**

```
var refreshIdd = setInterval(function() {
      loadData(page);
   },  <?= $h; ?>);
```

**For example:**
 If the time interval ie $h is 1000(1 sec) I have to call the function loadData with parameter 1. In the second second i have to call loadData 2.In Each time interval I have to pass 1,2,3 etc.If the $h is 2000 ie 2sec,I have to call loadData after 2nd second with parameter 1 and with parameter 2 in 4th second and so on
How can I do this?

Comment: diff param in the sense. Param differs in what way? what is the exact params you will pass? will it from db or randomwise or ???

Comment: I have to pass 1 in first time interval,2 in second and so on.if $h is 1000,I have to pass 1 in 1st second,2 in second second

Comment: So you want to pass *the number of seconds elapsed since loading the page*?

Comment: How is this question related to PHP?

Comment: @Oswald: Most of the persons working in PHP knows javascript too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is independent of `$h`.

Set `page = 1` and do a simple increment with `page++`. This would increase the value of `page` by 1 every time it is called.

```
var page = 1;
var refreshIdd = setInterval(function() {
    loadData(page++);
},  <?=$h?>);
```

See [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gC86v/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate function to get diff params.

```
var paramValue = 0;

var refreshIdd = setInterval(function() {
      param = getParam();
      loadData(param);
   },  <?= $h; ?>);

function getParam() {
   return ++paramValue;
}
```

(OR)

Simple as,

```
var paramValue = 0;    
var refreshIdd = setInterval(function() {
      loadData(++paramValue);
   },  <?= $h; ?>);
```